# How do I resolve this pubspec.yaml error?

Tags: flutter, pubspec.yaml

I facing a problem with my pubspec.yaml file. I added an image to my pubspec.yaml file, after adding it,when I run the `flutter pub get`, I got this error

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
> Unexpected child "To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this" found under "flutter".
> Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at /home/emmanuel/StudioProjects/gctu_app/pubspec.yaml
> Process finished with exit code 1

I also tried run `flutter clean`, `flutter build` , and`pub upgrade`, but that also produced the same error. Please how do I resolve it.

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Comment: show your code..

Comment: the pubspec.yaml code?

Comment: yes right only show the assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `#` before "  To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:"

so your yml is

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```